# How to determine which div/class a button has been clicked in

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css, ajax

This is my ajax post

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
  var num = 1;
  function ajax_post(){
  // Create our XMLHttpRequest object
  var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  // Create some variables we need to send to our PHP file
  var url = "javas.php";
  hr.open("POST", url, true);
   // Set content type header information for sending url encoded variables in the request
  hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  // Access the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest object
  hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
        var return_data = hr.responseText;
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = return_data;
    }
}
// Send the data to PHP now... and wait for response to update the status div
hr.send("num=" + (++num)); // Actually execute the request
document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "processing...";

}
</script>
```

Now I need to determine whitch class the button was clicked in (in php)

```
<?php
   //Getting posts from DB
   $event1 = mysql_query("SELECT post,date,memid FROM postaction WHERE memid = '$id' ORDER  BY date DESC LIMIT 5;");
  while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($event1))
  {
       $event = $row1['post'];
       $timeposted = $row1['date'];
       $eventmemdata = mysql_query("SELECT id,firstname FROM users WHERE id = '$id' LIMIT 1");
        while($rowaa = mysql_fetch_array($eventmemdata))
        {
            $name = $rowaa['firstname'];
            $eventlist = "$event <br> $name";
    }
        echo " <div id = 'eventer'> $timeposted <br>$eventlist</div> <input name='myBtn'            type='submit' value='increment' onClick='javascript:ajax_post();'>
               <input name='lol' type='submit' value='dec' onClick='javascript:ajax_posta();'>
               <div id = 'status'>lol</div>";
        echo "<br>";
  }
?>
</span>
</div>
```

When the button is clicked, the ajax function is called, however the function is being displayed in the first status div rather than in the div/class the button was clicked in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, you need to realize that "id" attribute of the tag is supposed to be unique. So the correct approach to implement this would be to differentiate the IDs for exemple appending a unique number to them. Kinda like this:

```
$i = 0;
while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($event1))
{
   $i++;

   ...

   echo " ... <input type='submit' name='lol' value='dec$i' />
       <div id='status$i'>...</div>";
}
```

You can then check for the number you get after the command (I know this is crude)

Comment: don't style ids, style classes, those are not needed to be unique

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery to find out which button has been clicked. Add a name attribute to your button.

```
    $().function({
      $("some_button").click() {
      clicked_name = $(this).attr("name");
      }
    });
```

Comment: they are all the same button im trying to figure out whitch class it was clicked in

Comment: Rather than trying to find out which class the button was clicked in, try finding out which button itself was clicked. You can distinguish your buttons, by giving them each a unique atrribute. Its always better to find the exact point of origin i.e your button, than finding out where that button is located :)

Answer (score 0):

You can update a hidden field with some relevant data and check it in post..

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
 echo " <div id = 'eventer'> $timeposted <br>$eventlist</div> <input name='myBtn'            type='submit' value='increment' onClick='javascript:ajax_post();'>
               <input name='lol' type='submit' value='dec' onClick='javascript:ajax_posta();'>
               <div id = 'status'>lol</div>";
        echo "<br>";
```

use

```
  echo " <div id = 'eventer'> $timeposted <br>$eventlist</div> <input name='myBtn'            type='submit' value='increment' onClick='javascript:ajax_post();'>
               <input name='lol' type='submit' value='dec' onClick='javascript:ajax_posta(this);'>
               <div id = 'status'>lol</div>";
        echo "<br>";
```

and in javascript you can easily get which one was clicked by using the whole object after receiving it you can use data- attributes or use the index